# No rule to make target error

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to `sudo make ubuntu-install` to compile Telephone Number Blocker from the [Murphy 101 blog](https://murphy101blog.wordpress.com/2013/11/03/raspberry-pi-telephone-number-blocker/).

I have a brand new Raspberry Pi 2, and have installed raspbian. So I assume it's the latest version.

Everything works fine in the instructions until entering the command `sudo make ubuntu-install`. It responds with:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'Ubuntu-install'.  Stop.

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure you typed `ubuntu-install` and not `Ubuntu-install` ?

Comment: I tried it both ways - no change. Still get the same response. "No rule to make target 'ubuntu-install'.  Stop."

Answer (score 2):

I found out the hard way that the directions at that point have you one folder too deep... back up so you are in the directory **~/Documents/source/ncid**. I got it to compile after that...